# Display the users that have not yet created projects this month (count=0)

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now I'm displaying the number of projects (projectName) opened by each user (userName)

```
SELECT COUNT(projectName) AS "Nombre de projets", userName AS "Nom de l'utilisateur"
FROM projects
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
GROUP BY userName
ORDER BY COUNT(projectName) DESC
```

I would like to display the users that have not yet created projects this month.

I've tried with several "join" example but I'm missing something.

Can you please help me?

Thank you

Comment: Share you DB structure to get accurate help

Comment: To get the result you are expecting, you need to use the USER table. Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be a calendar table with anti join approach:

```
SELECT u.userName
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT userName FROM projects) u
LEFT JOIN projects p
    ON u.userName = p.userName AND
       MONTH(p.date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
       YEAR(p.date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
WHERE
    p.userName IS NULL;
```

This assumes that you don't have a dedicated table containing all usernames.  In lieu of that, we can use the `projects` table itself as the source of truth for all users.  Note that we don't really need any sort of aggregation here, because we are just checking if there exists even one record for a given user in the current month and year, which would be evidence that the user created a project.